# How to Install Things off Command Line in Computer we are SSHed to

Tags: ssh, download

so my general problem right now is that I'm SSHing into another computer and would like to download Java, however a lot of what I would need to get things set up can only be accessed, from what I can tell so far, from a download off the web browser. Of course there are likely several solutions to this, such as ways to download the environment and language outside of a web browser, but at the same time I'd like to know the general strategies one would take in downloading new languages and environments on a computer they are SSHed into, or don't have as much utility in its use. Thank you!

Comment: 99% of the time if your using SSH: find the system package manager and see if you can use that.

Comment: what does finding the system's package manager entail? how would I do that on the command line? what system package managers are there, and are system package managers things that operator across languages?